# The set of zeros of an holomorphic function is closed and discrete

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $X$ a Banach space, $f:U\subseteq \mathbb{C}\to X$ an holomorphic function non constant and $N:=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:f(z)=0\right\}$. Show that $N$ is closed and discrete.

My idea:

The function $f$ is holomorphic, particulary $f$ is continuos. Then $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is colsed. Now, suppose that $N$ is not discrete, that is, $N$ has a limit point $\omega\in N$. The function $g=0$ satisfy that
$$f(x)=g(x),\hspace{0.2cm}\text{if }x\in N.$$
Finally, $N$ has at least one limit point and 
cause of the identity principle
$$f(x)=g(x)=0\hspace{0.1cm},\text{if }x\in U.$$

Questions:

1. Is it right?
2. Can I use the hypothesis $f$ non zero instead of non constant?

Thanks.

Comment: 1.Yes, that looks right and 2. yes, if $f$ is not the zero function and constant $N=\emptyset$ which is closed and discrete.

Comment: Hint $:$ Since $f$ is non constant the zeros of $f$ has no limit point by identity theorem.

Comment: 1. Right , 2. Right too.

Answer (score 2):

Identity Principle is for complex valued functions. Here you have to take $x^{*} \in X^{*}$ (where $X^{*}$ is the dual of $X$) and apply Identity Principle for $x^{*} \circ f$ to show that $x^{*} \circ f (z)=0$ for all $z$ for $x^{*}$ (if $N$ has a limit point). This implies $f(z)=0$ for all $z$.

Comment: there is an identity principle for Banach valued functions , see, e.g. http://www.ssmr.ro/bulletin/pdf/52-3/Dragomir.pdf theorem 12

Comment: Fine. What I did was to prove Identity Theorem for Banach valued holomorphic functions using the result for complex valued functions. You can ignore my answer, but there may be others who don't know the result for Banach valued case.

Comment: Could You add to Your answer the definition of $x^{\ast}$ and $B^{\ast}$?

Comment: I suppose You mean $X$ and $X^{\ast}$ instead of $B$...?I upvoted.